# How do I make a Polygon Pattern in Blender?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm creating a logo reveal for my business as it's in need of one, however we want the background to feature a polygon pattern that raps around the entire scene like a sphere. It must not be a texture either as we want it to be 3 dimensional. I would create one off the bat by adjusting some vertices but it doesn't look authentic enough. I've got a picture of the sort of pattern we want but we'd have it on a much larger scale.

http://www.superbwallpapers.com/vector/blue-polygon-28641/

Is there a modifier or generator that can produce such shapes?

Comment: Flat shading, triangulate, displace, sharp lighting, and low poly count

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise The main focus needs smooth shading. Would there be a way to separate the two somehow so only the low poly pattern has flat shading?

Comment: Flat shading for the specific object

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, was thinking of shadow casting being flat haha.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use a combination of the [*Displace*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier) and [*Decimate*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html#decimate-modifier) modifiers:

[image]

For the above image I used a UV sphere, but you'll notice some stretching at the poles. For this reason I found a icosphere with a high-ish amount of subdivisions (I used 6) works a bit better. I did not use any subsurf for the icosphere.

For the displace texture I used *Clouds* with a fairly small size (the size you want may vary depending on the size of your object and polygons):

To animate it, set the displace modifier to use another object for the texture coordinates. Add an empty at the center of the sphere and specify it in the displace modifier.

[image]

Then animate the scale of the empty:

[image]

---

[Dynamic topology sculpting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/dyntopo.html#dyntopo) can be used to create this effect with more control, but it may not be very convenient for animation.

Comment: An idea just popped to mind. Would I be able to use the ocean modifier to make the polys move randomly?

Comment: @Stewie That might work, but I think I'd use the displace modifier with an *Object Offset*. Updating answer..

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I'll have a play around and see how it goes.

Answer (score 7):

To your sphere add these modifiers.

1. Add a [Displace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier) modifier with a cloud texture as the texture.
2. Add a [Decimate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html#decimate-modifier) modifier, set to *Collapse*.

These are the modifiers on my grid object.
[image]

This is the result.
[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

You should use the *Displace* and *Triangulate* modifiers.

Start by adding (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and subdividing (<kbd>W</kbd>) a *Grid*:

[image: Add Grid]

Now add a Triangulate modifier, and then a Displace modifier. The triangulate modifier will make your mesh act as if it were created with triangular faces, and the Displace will move random vertices to give those faces a random slope/shadow. You may need to subdivide again to get the right size, or adjust the strength to get the right slope.

[image: Add Modifiers]

Now just make sure the lighting setup is as you want, and you are good to go. I noticed that a Sun Lamp at a bit of an angle seemed to make it much nicer. You can of course put the background on another Render-layer if it interferes with the lighting on the main subject.

[image: Final Result]